# Possible memory leak when using Cordova camera plug-in in Mobilefirst-based app on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, memory-leaks, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm experiencing application crash due to memory leak. Here is what happens.

1. Logged in to the app
2. App uses Cordova camera plug-in to capture images and shows them in grid from which I can remove and add images.
3. After some time the app becomes slow and at certain point it crashes

I observed memory allocations through Instruments in Xcode. When the app shows an image on screen the memory is allocated and it's not getting released even after I close that page or replace the contents with another image.

In the same way if I refresh the page on which images are shown, each time new memory is allocated without releasing old ones and memory allocation keeps on increasing and at one point app crashes.

I can't figure out how should I prevent the memory leak or release the allocated memory.

Here is how I am placing the images in HTML container:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<resultSet.Attachment.length; i++){ %>
     <li>
         <a class="img"><img width="224" src="<%= resultSet.Attachment[i].json.LOCAL_LOCATION %>" alt="" /></a>
         <div><textarea placeholder="No comments." readonly><%= resultSet.Attachment[i].json.DETAILS %></textarea></div>
     </li>
<% } %>
```

The app captures the image with camera plugin and gets the path where the image is stored and uses same path in src attribute of img tag to display image.

I am using:

- underscorejs to bind data to HTML template
- IBM Mobilefirst version 7.1
- Tested on iPad with iOS 10.0.2

Comment: thanks for response. I'll do the same. And in mean time should i try with newer version of IBM Mobilefirst?

Comment: For sure, updating is always a good try.

Comment: What if you are not using IBM MFP ? If you try the same code with a pure Cordova application , cordova-ios version 3.7.0 , do you see the same issue?

Comment: As Vivin suggested, in a pure Cordova application, does the same happen as well? Be sure to use though MFP Cordova app using MobileFirst CLI 7.1 so that the Cordova version will be the same.

Comment: @SanketK., any updates?

Comment: we are testing it as pure cordova app with newer version of cordova, and after that we'll upgrade MFP version. I'll come back with our observations.